# Is there a way to specify a culture for a COM call thread?

Tags: .net, com, interop, locale, culture

I'm working with a COM library via RCW, and I wonder if it is possible to change the locale of the thread which actually executes the COM call.
I'm targeting .NET 4.5.1.

I've tried usual .NET approach:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
```

but looks like it does not affect those COM call threads.

I've tried to set the culture before instantiating the RCW object and before the actual call which I want to run with specific locale setting.

I do not set the culture explicitly anywhere in the code, and the app has a single AppDomain.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't, that only affects the culture for newly created threads on .NET versions less than 4.6.  Use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture instead.  If the call gets marshalled to keep the COM object thread-safe then it gets murky, the culture of the owning thread matters.  Sometimes that will be a thread that COM creates if you don't help at all, extra murky.  You didn't give any relevant details, questions ought to have more text than comments.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the question to reflect more details. Also, MSDN says that CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture also sets the current thread culture for all threads that don't have the culture set explicitly in the current AppDomain